# iOS Skipping a Method Call From Another View

Tags: ios, function, methods, uiviewcontroller

I've looked up about a dozen different pages, both on how to call methods from other views and instances when the method is being skipped, but no answer has come.

I'm going to be thorough here. Two relevant classes:

SpeakersView

and

GetData

GetData is just there because I'm going to need to call that method from half a dozen different classes, best to just write it once.

Here's GetData.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GetData : UIViewController
-(NSArray *)getTableArray:(NSString *)section :(NSString *)entity;
@end
```

Here's GetData.m:

```
@interface GetData (){

    NSArray *tableData;
    NSArray *titleData;
    NSArray *splitData;

}

@end

@implementation GetData

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSArray *)getTableArray:(NSString *)section :(NSString *)entity{
//Code omitted. Shouldn't really have anything to do with why the method is being skipped.
}

@end
```

So here's how I'm calling the method in SpeakersView.m:

```
GetData *GD;

menu_List = [GD getTableArray:@"Speakers" :@"John Smith"];
```

Recommendations? I should mention I've had no problem calling other methods in exactly the same way from different classes.

Comment: And for sure you are initializing GD in SpeakersView, right?

Comment: You did actually instantiate a `GetData` object, right? Sample code above shows otherwise. No `GetData` object, no data.

Comment: I didn't need to instantiate the other methods before. Sorry, this is only my second iOS app, so I sometimes forget some of the terms. What do I have to do to instantiate it?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite confident I'm calling it from SpeakersView.m

Comment: You need GetData *GD = [[GetData alloc] init];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetData *GD;` doesn't initialize the `UIViewController`. It's nil at that point, so you cannot call a method on it.

Try:

`GetData *GD = [[GetData alloc] init];`

Also, why is `GetData` a `UIViewController`? Make it an `NSObject`, you don't need a whole view controller with all of its bulk if you're just using it for that method.

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I'll check you off once the timer runs out. IT's a UIViewController because that's what the default setting was when I created it, and I forgot to remove it.

Comment: You can also create new classes and choose `NSObject`, which you should probably do for this kind of class. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Calling a class "GetData" that inherits an UIViewController shows clearly a huge conception problem. A controller is a class that feed its views with the model (in the MVC pattern). It's not an utility class.

In your example you're also not instantiating the controller.

Comment: GetData inheriting UIViewController was an accident, left over from the previous class I created.